# Error fetching data: FetchError: invalid json response body

Tags: node.js, express, server, postman, fetch

I am a newbie in NodeJS. I am trying to get json response from this online API using this code

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const apiUrl = "https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=28.6083697&lng=77.293112&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING"; // Replace with the actual API URL
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
    const data = await response.json();
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

When I try to do a get request I am getting this error in console

```
Server is running on port 3001
Error fetching data: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=28.6083697&lng=77.293112&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING reason: Unexpected token '<', "<html lang"... is not valid JSON
    at /home/priya/Documents/server/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:273:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /home/priya/Documents/server/index.js:15:18 {
  type: 'invalid-json'
}
```

I tried to console log the response I am getting

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _events: [Object],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _eventsCount: 5,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=28.6083697&lng=77.293112&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING',
    status: 403,
    statusText: 'Forbidden',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

I looked up multiple stackoverflow answers but couldn't figure out the issue in here. Please help

Answer (score 0):

you are getting status: 403, which means the request is forbidden. I have managed to run this is in a separate environment.
if you use axios then in response you can check data in html response of that server i am adding a screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: if you are curious of axios i am adding a snippet.

Comment: const response = await axios.get(apiUrl)
 return res.json(data);

Comment: and in catch
res.send(error.response.data)